# Проблема с отображением даты

Tags: битрикс

мне нужно отобразить дату создания новости.
В цикле я написал [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но оно не работает.
Потом я переписал на это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и все равно не отображается дата
Помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А она вообще есть в массиве ?
`<pre><?print_r($arItem)?></pre>` пробовали. Если даты все еще нет то посмотрите компонент установлен ли вывод даты создания в настройках

Comment: всё работает, спасибо ( ˙꒳​˙ )

Comment: @ВладКурганов тогда отметьте вопрос как принятый (галочка слева от ответа) ^_^